# Text search in mongodb and sort with score in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have collection of resturant. Sample as below :

_id : 61404857769a66cb055a5f2c
address:"388 Filton Avenue"
address line 2:"Bristol"
name:"1st Class Pizza"
rating:4.5
type_of_food:"Pizza"
zipcode:"BS70BE"

Here user provides a string to be searched in the address field and a minimum rating. The query returns all restaurant names and cuisine that match the inputs provided along with the match score. Sort output by descending score.

Need help with python

My code -->

```
#user input    
    mytext=input("Please provide a string to be searched in the address field : \n")
    minrating=input("Please provide a minimum rating : \n")

#index
    restaurant.create_index([('address','text')])

#I tried this but it's not working
    print(restaurant.find({"rating": {"$gte":minrating }} and { $text: { "$search": mytext } },{score:{ "$meta": "textScore"}}).sort({score:{ "$meta":textScore}}))
```

Comment: Can someone help me with this Python Code -->
cursor=restaurant.find({
        { "rating" : {"$gte" : minrating }},
        { "$text"  : {"$search" : mytext }},
        { "score"  : {"$meta" : "textScore"}}
        })

cursor.sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})])


Error --> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add "and" after each field you want to filter.

try this:

```
restaurant.find(
{
  rating: {"$gte":minrating },
  {$text:{$search:mytext }},
  {score: { "$meta":"textScore" }}
}).sort({score: { $meta:"textScore"}})
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting below error with updated code -->
cursor=restaurant.find({
        { "rating" : {"$gte" : minrating }},
        { "$text"  : {"$search" : mytext }},
        { "score"  : {"$meta" : "textScore"}}
        })

cursor.sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})])


Error --> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: please use the exact code i edited for you.
do not use cursor.sort after.

Comment: `code --> 
restaurant.create_index([('address','text')])
for record in restaurant.find({ 
    { "$text"  : {"$search" : mytext }},
    { "score"  : {"$meta" : "textScore"}}
    }).sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})]):
    print(record)

Error --> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'